# Any ideas to implement a simple 2D sky?

Tags: c++, sfml

I need a very simple sky with simple day/night cycle. In my implementation
the 'sky' is just a simple dynamically created gradient background, based on two colors.

[For example](http://img14.deviantart.net/ff6c/i/2012/009/1/a/sky_gradient_stock_by_nikhilmoh-d4lt15o.jpg)

My question is: There is a simple formula or any other solution to dynamically 'change' the rgb colors of gradient by the angle of 'sun', or by the actual gametime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some research about this in 3D (spherical). For implementing this in 2D, you could for instance use x and y as latitude and longitude and use these for generating a 3D direction vector.

These models are somewhat complex though, I don't sink they are elligible to your "simple" requirement...

[Preetham sky model](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/sunsky.pdf)

[Hosek-Wilkie sky model](http://cgg.mff.cuni.cz/projects/SkylightModelling/)